# Showing $D = \{ f : |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|} \}$ where $D \subseteq C[0,1]$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Given $D = \{f: |f(x) - f(y)| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|}\}$ where $D \subseteq C[0,1]$, I am asked to show this set is not compact. To do so, I must show the set is not bounded (specifically not uniformly equi-bounded). However, I feel that it is.

Suppose $f_n \in D$ and so $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$. However $x, y \in [0,1]$ so $\max(\sqrt{|x-y|}) = 1$.

This means $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| \leq \sqrt{|x-y|} ≤ 1$. Can I not claim that then there exists M such that $|f_n(x)| < M$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$ and for all $n$?

I appreciate any help that can be provided. Thank you!

Comment: Take the collection of functions $f_n(x) = n$. They all lie in $D$ but clearly are not bounded.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought of that. Thank you @copper.hat . So I'm guessing just by saying $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < M$ is not enough to prove that there exists L such that  $|f_n(x)| < L$ for all x and all n?

Comment: That is correct. The restriction above just limits the change in the function, but if the function is constant, then there is no change hence it lies in $D$.

Comment: Ah and I was also stuck on the idea that since $f_n$ are continuous and [0,1] is compact then $f_n([0,1])$ is compact as well and hence why it's bounded. But I suppose such a property doesn't restrict $f_n([0,1])$ from getting increasingly larger as n approaches infinity? @copper.hat

Comment: and I'm referring to general $f_n \in D$ with my above comment @copper.hat